# Excel VBA - Run Time Automation Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error

I have this below VBA code (pretty common found on this site itself as well as other places on the net to find SHA hash in VBA) that works just fine in Excel 2013 on Windows 7 32.

However the same code when run in Excel 2003 SP3 on Windows 7 32  gives Run Time Automation Error at line Set asc1 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")

I am unclear why it is failing in Excel 2003.  Assuming it has something to do with dot net framework I re-installed dot Net 4.0 while 3.5.1 is already part of Windows 7 and Feature already enabled.

There is very similar post on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988123/error-in-hash-implementation-in-vba-runtime-error-2146232576-80131700) but even it does not have a solution.  What else should I troubleshoot further? Could this be something to do with missing or corrupt components / libraries or anything related?

Thanks.

```
 Public Function SHA1(str1)
    Dim asc1 As Object
    Dim enc1 As Object
    Dim bytes, outstr, pos
    Set asc1 = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider")
    bytes = asc1.GetBytes_4(str1)
    bytes = enc1.ComputeHash_2((bytes))
    outstr = ""

    For pos = 1 To LenB(bytes)
        outstr = outstr & LCase(Right("0" & Hex(AscB(MidB(bytes, pos, 1))), 2))
    Next
    SHA1 = outstr

    Set asc1 = Nothing
    Set enc1 = Nothing


End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim txt
txt = TextBox1.Text
TextBox2.Text = SHA1(txt)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In the VBA Editor window, under Tools -> References, are any listed as missing on the machine/setup having the issue?

Comment: @panhandel - Thanks for your input. How do I know if something is missing? Default ones are tick marked plus I already added System, mscorlib & MSXML5

Comment: Any missing would be prefixed with "MISSING: " like the 6th one on this pic: http://www.cpearson.com/images/MissingRef.png

Comment: Ok got it. Nothing is missing in that case.

Comment: I also kinda completely glazed over the fact that you were going backwards from 2013 to 2003, in which case, it's not at all uncommon to have an upgraded dll referenced in 2013 which isn't backwards compatible to 2003.  You would need to look through the reference list and see if you can find a highest common denominator of that dll to reference for both to work.

Comment: Well I have Excel 2003.  I just managed to borrow a friends laptop that has 2013 for testing purposes.

Comment: Quick last note; sometimes moving to a newer Office version will automatically upgrade a reference, so you might be able to just remove the reference back in 2003, and re-add whatever version it has available to make it work again.

Comment: http://p2p.wrox.com/vbscript/29099-unicode-utf-8-system-text-utf8encoding-vba.html#post272370

Comment: Taking inputs from  post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok  I installed  Update KB907417 for Office 2003 and issue is resolved!

Comment: If you've solved it, please post a self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar issue was discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375457/cant-instantiate-a-com-object-written-in-c-sharp-from-vba-vb6-ok  on Stackoverflow.com.
The user got same "automation error" 0x80131700 in Excel VBA.

Taking inputs from the posted answers therein, I installed Office 2003 Update KB907417 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10624  and  the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved by installing the .NET Framework 3.5: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=21

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.